# XSL Output declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, declaration

I need to output declaration to XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I try convert HTML to XML.
My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
        method="xml" 
        encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"   
        indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this script gives the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: How are you executing the XSLT exactly, is the XSLT processor in charge of the serialization of the result of the transformation? Basically we need precise information on how to reproduce the issue to tell how to fix it.

Comment: Notepad++ with XML Tools or Free online XSL Transformer (freeformatter.com)

Comment: I think Notepad++ with XML Tools uses MSXML, it might be difficult with MSXML to force to output the properties given in `xsl:output`. No idea what freeformatter uses but your XSLT is fine, the XSLT processor just needs to be in charge of the serialization and needs to support it (which is usually the case if you write directly to a file(stream) but often not if a string is the intermediary result).

Comment: Thanks! In this case, I will not pay attention to the declaration.